# Programmin In C + Win API: Launching A Second Window When A Button Is Pressed

Tags: c, winapi

I am writing a program in C and Windows API. I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express for this.

I have created a Login Window that well, logs in the user. Now, I want to display a second window once user logs in.

How can I do that?
P.S. I am a beginner and am following this tutorial: http://www.zetcode.com/tutorials/winapi/ . Some simple solution will do.

Answer (score 1):

You create the window by 
defining a WindProc 
Calling [RegisterClassEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Call [CreatewindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)